# Using nested for loops to iterate through JSON file of tweets in Python

Tags: python, json, twitter

So I am new to Python, but I know what I am trying to accomplish. Basically, I have the output of tweets from twitter in a JSON file loaded into Python. What I need to do is iterate through the tweets to access the "text" key, that has the text of each tweet, because that's what I'm going to use to do topic modeling. So, I have discovered that "text" is triple nested in this data structure, and it's been really difficult to find the correct way to write the for loop code in order to iterate through the dataset and pull the "text" from every tweet.

Here is a look at what the JSON structure is like: https://pastebin.com/fUH5MTMx

So, I have figured out that the "text" key that I want is within [hits][hits][_source]. What I can't figure out is the appropriate for loop to iterate through _source and pull those texts. Here is my code so far (again I'm very beginning sorry if try code is way off):

```
for hits in tweets["hits"]["hits"]:
        for _source in hits:
            for text in _source:
                for item in text:
                    print(item)
```

also tried this:

```
for item in tweets['hits']["hits"]["_source"]:
        print(item['text'])
```

But I keep getting either syntax errors for the first one then "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" for the second one. I am understanding that I need to specify some way that I am trying to access this list, and that I'm missing something in order to show that its a list and I am not looking for integers as an output from iterations...(I am using the JSON module in Python for this, an using a Mac with Python3 in Spyder)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated! This multiple nesting is confusing me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`['hits']["hits"]` is not dictionary with `["_source"]`
but a list with one or many items which have `["_source"]`
it means

```
tweets['hits']["hits"][0]["_source"]

tweets['hits']["hits"][1]["_source"]

tweets['hits']["hits"][2]["_source"]
```

So this should work

```
for item in tweets['hits']["hits"]:
    print(item["_source"]['text'])
```

Comment: Thank you this helped! I used that and then made a new list with only the text in it so I can then just work with the text.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you realize it, but JSON is transformed into a Python dictionary, not a list. Anyway, let's get into this nest.

`tweets['hits']` will give you another dict.

`tweets['hits']['hits']` will give you a list (notice the brackets)

This apparently is a list of dictionaries, and in this case (not sure if it will always be), the dict with the "_source" key you are looking for is the first one,so:

`tweets['hits']['hits'][0]` will give you the dict you want. Then, finally:

`tweets['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']` should give you the text.

Comment: Thank you, this helped as well, I was confused by dictionaries and lists so this helps me understand what I'm working with better.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the second "hits" is a list.

Try:

```
for hit in tweets["hits"]["hits"]:
     print(hit["_source"]["text"])
```